# Why isn't ggplot2 able to handle a .csv Dataset with text and values?

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2

I am trying to interpret data which i collected in an ecological fieldwork.

Therefor I started to work with R and RStudio.

Both programs are able to handle the .csv which I feed them.

I went on to try to work with ggplot2 because I have problems getting the results I am looking for. I was hoping for even more intuitiveness, as I am not a coder.

But when I am trying to upload my [dataset](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=43232715174136478110) I get this error message:

```
R catched an error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I cannot find out where to problem with ggplot2 is.

For people who dont want to download the dataset, thats the format:

```
Pstelle,Pgrube,Gattung,Art,Alter,Masse
9,2,NA,NA,NA,0.09
9,2,Dendrobaena,NA,juv,0.10
9,2,Allolobophora,NA,juv,0.09
9,4,Allolobophora,chlorotica,juv,0.14
```

with the first line being the (german) header.

System info: Windows 7, Firefox 39.0, RR x64 3.2.2, RStudio Version 0.99.473

Comment: The dataframe is the basic building block of R and that is the sort of object for which the functions of ggplot2 were designed to process.

Comment: your dataset link is broken.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you are trying to plot or how you are trying to get your data in. Include the code you used to read your csv and attempts at ggplot. Here's something that should work a little - `dat <-read.csv("filename.csv"); library(ggplot2); ggplot(dat, aes(y=Masse, x=Pgrube, col=Gattung)) +geom_point()`